# How to download/consume published artifacts using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to publish artifacts to private-GitLab with two dependencies(Web and Actuator) as below

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://<gitlab-url>/repo"
        name "GitLab"
        credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
            name = 'Private-Token'
            value = gitLabPrivateToken
        }
        authentication {
            header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
        }
    }
}
```

But not sure I am facing 401 error. I replaced git URL with local directory and it got succeeded. I can see metadata and pom files generated. When consuming the artifacts from local directory in another project using below **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
         maven {
            url "C://<location>//gradle-test"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.gradle:gradleproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    }
}
```

I am facing the below error.

```
C:\Users\root\gradle>gradle build

> Task :buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
\--- com.gradle:gradleproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE
     |    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.6.RELEASE
     |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.6.RELEASE
     |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.6.RELEASE
     |    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE
     |    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.6.RELEASE
     |    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
     |    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
     |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
     |    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.13.2
     |    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
     |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.2
     |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.30
     |    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
     |    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
     |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0
     |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
     |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
     |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.5.1
     |         +--- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:2.1.12
     |         \--- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:2.0.3
     \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.0.RELEASE
          +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
          +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.3.0.RELEASE
          |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
          |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.6.RELEASE
          |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
          |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
          |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
          |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.0
          |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
          |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
          |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.0 (*)
          |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.11.0
          |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
          |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
          +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.3.0.RELEASE
          |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
          |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.35
          |    +--- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:3.0.3
          |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.35
          |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.35
          +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
          \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.6.RELEASE
               +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
               +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
               +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
               +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
               +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
               \--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Can Someone help me where I made a mistake or how to resolve this error? and Is this the right way to consume?

Answer (score 0):

The following example demonstrates how to sign and publish a Java library including sources, Javadoc, and a customized POM:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'signing'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0'

java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'my-library'
            from components.java
            versionMapping {
                usage('java-api') {
                    fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                }
                usage('java-runtime') {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
            pom {
                name = 'My Library'
                description = 'A concise description of my library'
                url = 'http://www.example.com/library'
                properties = [
                    myProp: "value",
                    "prop.with.dots": "anotherValue"
                ]
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name = 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
                        url = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id = 'johnd'
                        name = 'John Doe'
                        email = 'john.doe@example.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection = 'scm:git:git://example.com/my-library.git'
                    developerConnection = 'scm:git:ssh://example.com/my-library.git'
                    url = 'http://example.com/my-library/'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            // change URLs to point to your repos, e.g. http://my.org/repo
            def releasesRepoUrl = "$buildDir/repos/releases"
            def snapshotsRepoUrl = "$buildDir/repos/snapshots"
            url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
        }
    }
}

signing {
    sign publishing.publications.mavenJava
}


javadoc {
    if(JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible()) {
        options.addBooleanOption('html5', true)
    }
}
```

The result is that the following artifacts will be published:

- The POM: `my-library-1.0.pom`
- The primary JAR artifact for the Java component: `my-library-1.0.jar`
- The sources JAR artifact that has been explicitly configured: `my-library-1.0-sources.jar`
- The Javadoc JAR artifact that has been explicitly configured: `my-library-1.0-javadoc.jar`

The [Signing Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html#signing_plugin) is used to generate a signature file for each artifact. In addition, checksum files will be generated for all artifacts and signature files.

Refer to this link:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

Comment: Hi @wuchunfu, Thanks for the response. Can you tell me how to connect/consume the artifacts generated using **build.gradle**

Comment: Refer to this link:

https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-libraries/

Comment: I hope you understood the use-case which I am facing. It's not about the building, I want to consume the generated artifacts from the local repo. Please Can you share with me some example build scripts that connect to the local repo so that it will download the dependencies generated from the publish part as you shared/mentioned in the topic?